# Grub Not Showing, System Bootorder Not Found, Ubuntu & Windows 10

Tags: ubuntu, boot, windows, dual-boot, grub

I have installed ubuntu in dual boot with windows 10 in UEFI mode. Can't boot to ubuntu. The error message "System Bootorder Not Found" flashes and then Windows 10 boots up. I tried some solutions present on this topic but I can't seem to get them to work. I am a beginner in terms of linux. Please Help!
P.S: Laptop Model HP Elitebook 8570w.

Comment: HP often boots once, or manually from UEFI boot menu. But it does not keep boot order change using efibootmgr which every other UEFI system recognizes. You have to go into UEFI/BIOS settings & change boot order in boot tab, not UEFI boot menu. Some HP have this: HP put a fail-safe gpt recovery into the UEFI Settings,  go into the UEFI Menu in Security -> Hard Drive Utilities -> Uncheck "Save/restore GPT System of Hard Drive" https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2412901 HP - escape + F9 for boot menu, F10 for bios setup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem. This question has been answered on this [forum](https://askubuntu.com/questions/554690/hp-uefi-doesnt-boot-ubuntu-automatically)

> The path that needs to be entered as the Custom Boot image is:

> When using Secure Boot: EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi
> When not using Secure Boot: EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi

> This is one of two workarounds. The other would be to copy /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/(grub|shim)x64.efi to /boot/efi/EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi.

This seems to be a specific HP bug. The solution that worked for me was to enable secure boot, set the custom boot path to EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi and bring the custom boot option top in the boot order.